# Teams toolkit Hello World Bot with SSO, show command not working

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I am trying out the **Hello World Bot with SSO** sample which comes with the **Teams toolkit**.

"Show" command is not working as expected for me, getting a response as

> There is an issue while trying to sign you in and retrieve your profile photo, please type "show" command to login and consent permissions again.

or

> "We need to ask for additional permissions. You should only need to do this once for MyApplication" with two buttons "Cancel" and "Continue".

On clicking "Continue" no action is happening.

On debugging found that, tokenResponse.ssoToken is not getting set.

Any pointer on how to overcome it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please test this with user who has profile photo set on his account?

Comment: 1. Do you have a profile picture set?
2. Have you configured SSO in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Have you checked this with profile photo set?

Comment: After providing additional permissions I am not seeing the issue now. Also profile photo is not set. @Nivedipa-MSFT

Comment: Could you please share what additional permissions you have provide to fix the issue, so that others can also be benefited out of it?